# Conflicting versions of ASP.NET Web Pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok so I have used the nuget UpgradeMvc3ToMvc4 to upgrade my site to MVC4, and once i resolved some other errors i am now stuck at this one.

> Conflicting versions of ASP.NET Web Pages detected: specified version
>   is "2.0.0.0", but the version in bin is "1.0.0.0". To continue, remove
>   files from the application's bin directory or remove the version
>   specification in web.config.

I want it to be version 2.0 but why is it version 1.0 in the bin? I have cleared the bin and rebuilt and it's still the same error, I only have references to 2.0 in my project and my web.config so what can be causing this?

this is not the same as the question marked as the answer, although the error is close, i have referenced 2.0 everywhere but for some reason 1.0 is apparently in the bin! as i have said above i have tried all of those steps and nothing works..

Looking into this a bit more, i can see i have a _bin_deployableassemblies folder, but i also have a base packages folder under the project and most of the dlls in each of these folders are different version as far as i can see.

Comment: If you read it properly it hasn't, everyone asks it the other way e.g. specified version is 1.0 and version in the bin is 2.0.0 i have read and tried the solutions from 100 of them.

Comment: (is open again) you need to mention what you have try that is different from the other answers or else, looks like you do not have try anything. https://www.google.com/search?q=Conflicting+versions+of+ASP.NET+Web+Pages+detected%3A+specified+version+is+%222.0.0.0%22&oq=Conflicting+versions+of+ASP.NET+Web+Pages+detected%3A+specified+version+is+%222.0.0.0%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: i have tried absolutely everything, i have spent ages on this I don't just post at the first hurdle thanks. this is a big project that I am trying to  upgrade not a first try.